# Do we need to include normalize after using Pure css?

Tags: css, yui-pure-css

I think Yahoo's [Pure](http://purecss.io/) is awesome. But I was thinking, do we need to include normalize.css after using Pure?

Answer (score 10):

It is not needed seperately as Pure builds on Normalize.css and provides layout and styling for native HTML elements, plus the most common UI components. It's what you need, without the cruft.

You can find the normalize.css file in this folder.

```
pure-master\src\base\css
```

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, it's good to know that pure is at this moment base on version 1.1.2 of normalize.css (as you can see there: http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/base.css), to keep IE6 and Safari 4+ in the supported browsers list.
Now, normalize.css's latest version is 2.1.3 (IE 8+, Firefox 4+, Safari 5+, Opera, Chrome). See https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/v2.1.3/CHANGELOG.md for more details.

The thing I don't know is when Pure.css will drop IE6, and will decide to take normalize.css 2.x as a base.

Comment: A lot later now, but pure 0.6.0 uses normalize 3.x  http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/base.css